# wordpress 4.5 automatic Login with PHP CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, cookies, authentication

I'm using php curl for automatic login into wordpress panel but code does n't work

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$postData = array('log'=> 'admin',
  'pwd' => '123',
  'wp-submit' => '%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AF',
  'redirect_to' => 'http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/',
  'testcookie' => '1'
);
$cookie = basename('cookie.txt');
$opt = array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/wp/wp-login.php',
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0',
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie
);
curl_setopt_array($ch,$opt);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
echo $out;
?>
```

wordpress login panel return :

ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

How do fix error

Answer (score 0):

**Your Login function :**

```
function Login($data){
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sbx/wp-config.php');
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sbx/wp-load.php');
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sbx/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
 global $db;
 global $json;

 $credentials = array();

 $secure_cookie='';

 $username=$_POST['user_login'];
 $password=$_POST['user_pass'];

 if ( !empty($_POST['remember']) )
        $credentials['remember'] = true;
    else
        $credentials['remember'] = false;

    $secure_cookie = apply_filters( 'secure_signon_cookie', $secure_cookie, $credentials );

    global $auth_secure_cookie;
    $auth_secure_cookie = $secure_cookie;

    add_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_cookie', 30, 3);

 $user = wp_authenticate($username, $password);

 if ( ! is_wp_error($user) )
 {
  $json['success'] = true;
  $json['data'] = $user;

 } else {
  $json['success'] = false;
  $json['data'] = "Please Wrong Username And Password.";
 }
```

**Your Curl format:**

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"your_url");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user_login=dcm&user_pass=123456&api=Login");

    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
```

Comment: I used this function to run API which uses backend login and after log in you can redirect to the url you want.

Comment: this code dos n't work , Curl Can't Login , Cookie dosn't set